# Cargar datos de un arreglo a datatables

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, datatables, vuejs

por favor me pueden ayudar con un problema que se me presento.
Tengo una tabla que deseo diseñar con datatables y vuejs. pero no se como hacerlo, al cargar la pagina cargo una tabla con una id "example"
y en el método de mi javascript tengo lo siguiente

```js
 var table = $('#example').DataTable();
    table.destroy();
    table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        data: ??,
        destroy: true,
        empty: false,
        columns: [
            { title: "Fecha Entrega" },
            { title: "Rut" },
            { title: "Cliente" },
            { title: "Condominio" },
            { title: "Numero Vivienda" },
            { title: "Tipo Vivienda" },
            { title: "RM" },
            { title: "RCBR" },
            { title: "Acción" }
        ]
    } );
```

Que funciona, limpia mi tabla la crea nuevamente pero no entiendo como puedo hacerlo para rellenarla con mis datos, ya que tengo un arreglo que recibo con axios llamado listaViviendas

¿Como puedo rellenar el datatables con la información y que funcionen los filtros y las propiedades de datatables correctamente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías hacer que la data que esta leyendo tu tabla sea una computed que retorne la data que se actualizara con con la peticion axios que vayas a hacer, o hacer tu axios en el mounted metodo

```
  mounted () {
axios
  .get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
  .then(response => (this.info = response))}
```

Comment: Gracias amigo es justo lo que necesitaba!